# How to change class of dymanic row of a table in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic table in angular2

```
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let dataList of dataLists; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
<td>{{dataList.Name}}</td>
<td><div (click)="onClick(i)"><span class="glyphicon"  [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': opendPanel , 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !opendPanel }"></span></div></td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The last column is a down arrow (glyphicon-chevron-up) which on click should change to (glyphicon-chevron-down)
My problem is that once clicked all the rows icon is changed. I want to change only icon of row selected.

Comment: You need a status for every row. Either add a proeprty to `dataList` or add another array to your component with the same size as `dataLists` and then use `dataList.selected` or `myArray[i]` to store the status of the icon. If you have only one status for all icons created by `*ngFor` they all need to have the same status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single Boolean variable **opendPanel**.That's why changing its value affects all other rows of the table.

To accomplish your task, you can have new property in **dataList** object and use it like below:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dataList of dataLists; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <td>{{dataList.Name}}</td>
    <td><div (click)="onClick(i,dataList)"><span class="glyphicon"  [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': dataList.opendPanel , 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !dataList.opendPanel }"></span></div></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

At the component side, set the value of **dataList.opendPanel** in the onClick event.

Hope it helps!!